# HTML code to HTML in Textview

Tags: android, html, textview

I am receiving a webservice strings in html code, and needed to put them in this html code to put a TextView.

Example:

```java
String str = "&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;/b&gt;";

// my attempt
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str)); 
// this only convert to <b>Hello</b> instead of running the html code.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that's an ugly trick but it works:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(str).toString()));
```